# Special Characters in MySQL using UTF8 Unicode Collation and LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, utf-8, unicode

I have several csv files in am loading into MySQl using Java. In the Description field I have several Special Characters that are causing the load to fail. I am using LOAD DATA INFILE. This is nested in a for each loop which parses an array of filenames / tables and runs through each combination until it is finished with all the files.

Here is my jdbc connection string where I am passing a definitive collation param/value for UTF8 collation

```
 static String  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stage?verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8";
```

Here is my LOAD DATA string.

```
final String sql2 = ("LOAD DATA INFILE" + filetoEat  +
       "INTO TABLE staging." +tableName +
       "CHARACTER SET UTF8
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY','  ENCLOSED BY '\"\'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  IGNORE 1 LINES");
```

Create Table Statement

```
CREATE TABLE `zmi064_02` (
  `Material` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Material Description` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatType` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `MatGrp` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `ClassType` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `Class type Text` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `Class` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `Class Text` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `CharactName` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `CharactValue` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `Plant` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Show variables

```
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database      utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        utf8
character_set_system        utf8
collation_connection        utf8_general_ci
collation_database          utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server            utf8_general_ci
```

The code is working fine until it comes across a special character like a degree symbol or micro symbol µ within a Material Description . At that point it throws an Exception

```
Invalid utf8 character string: 'LUG'
```

The string LUG is followed by a µ symbol. The DB is set to utf8 - utf8_unicode_ci and the column in question is a VARCHAR(60) that holds material descriptions. I have tried using  ESCAPED BY '\' but I can't seem to get it working correctly. I have also tried CHARACTER SET UTF8. I have also tried different collation ie, utf8_general_ci to no avail.

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: Add the charset clause to your `LOAD DATA` statement.

Comment: It is part of my load data string, I edited my post and added the LOAD DATA INFILE string.. Thanks

Comment: Can you get the hex of the `µ` in the input.  If you get `B5`, then it is latin1; if you get `C2B5`, then it is utf8.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, it turns out to be UTF-8 but i never thought to check. This data comes out of a Unicode SAP environment in Spain so it could have been.

Comment: Well, I am stumped.  "Truncation" is caused by non-utf8 bytes being stored into utf8 column.  (If the source were latin1, you could change that clause in the `LOAD DATA` to make it work -- MySQL will transcode it as it store it.)

Comment: I have been working this for a couple weeks and have tried different collation and encoding. Changed the table collation to Latin1 and even the  Description field itself. But I am still getting the same exception. If I run this csv through Table Import in Wworkbench it will load the rows that are ok and skip the others. In my Java code I am catching the exception in a try catch clause so I am seeing the error. I will figure it out, but it is a stumper for sure. Thanks a lot for your help, I do appreciate the effort.

Comment: Sorry.  I have been struggling for years with charset issues.  I see 5 distinct symptoms.  Yours is different in that it involves `LOAD DATA`, not `INSERT`.  Still, the only cause for truncation that I have found is the wrong encoding in the source string.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You got me thinking in the right direction and I figured it out and got it working

Comment: @RickJames I know this isn't new but I recommend adding your comment regarding trying latin1 and/or a different encoding for the LOAD DATA command.
That's a great point and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured that I would answer this now that I found the solution. Because I am using Java to run the `LOAD DATA INFILE` via JDBC the JDBC driver seems to be checking the collation at the DB and not the actual table being loaded as it is parsing the file. So you can't have the DB set to UTF-8 and have a Latin collated table as you would be able to do with an `INSERT` statement. I had tried to set the Table collation as Latin and even had the field in question Latin, but until I changed the entire DB to Latin it was failing. The CSV files are large so checking every char in question is not easy, but I was catching the Exceptions in Java and was able to determine that the error was generated by the JDBC driver and was complaining that "Character at line xx is not a UTF-8 character" Running in Debug allowed me to see more details.

I then concluded it must not be looking at the Latin collated table it would be filling, but was looking at the DB which was still set to UTF-8. Changing the DB to Latin was all I needed to do.

I want to thank @Rick James for his help, I hope this will help others in the future.

Pat

Comment: Hmmm...  The charset of the _database_ is used only as the _default_ when creating a _table_ in that database.  Similarly, the charset for the _table_ is just a default for the columns in case you do not explicitly state a charset for them.  And...

Comment: The bytes in the client (the CSV files) do _not_ need to agree with the charset of the columns they go into.  _But_, you _must_ establish what charset encoding (latin1 or utf8, etc) those bytes are in.  This is done via the connection or load data or set names.